Run a query based on the output of a condition in Oracle sql
I have this table with column name as "IdentificationNo", "InformationType", "datefield" and "vauleAmount". Now based on the value of these fields, I want to run another query in the same table as explained below:
Let's say if for a given IdentificationNo (123), (informationType = 'abc' and datefield is not empty) AND, for the same IdentificationNo (123) there is a row with (informationType = 'xyz' and valueAmount=0) present too then I want to ignore such rows from the returned resulset.

So, if there is 1 row present with 'abc' informationType with identificationNo '123' and (datefield is not empty) and and 1 row with 'xyz' for the same identificationNo and ( valueAmount=0) then returned resultset returned should be empty.

AND,

If informationType is not 'abc' then don't look further for 'xyz' informationType and return null. i.e 0 rows

AND,
3. If there is just 'abc' informationType for a give identificationNo is present, return it in the resultset.
There is only table involved here and can have different informationType. Here, I am just concerned for 'abc' and 'xyz'. One identificationNo can have multiple entries with different informationTypes.
As per this sample data: Since IdenticationNo '123' has both 'abc' and 'xyz' information present and they fullfil the 1st condition too , so, the query should not return any row.
  SELECT '123', 'abc', DATE '1970-01-01', 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '123, 'xyz', DATE '1970-01-02',   0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '123', 'xyz', DATE '1970-01-03', 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '123', 'def', DATE '1970-01-04', 300 FROM DUAL;

Can it be achieved using a query? I cannot use PL/SQL.

hi bro did you tried by inner join if not please show me your both table columns
and also output which you want.

There is only 1 table here. inforamtionType is the column and based on the value of that I need the output as asked above.

SELECT * FROM InfotTable WHERE (ITYPE1 = abc AND ITYPE2 = xyz)  OR (ITYPE1 = abc)

how many type column you have

@SandeepPareek The question states "table with a column name "InformationType"" - so there is one column.

you checking for two different value 'abc' and 'xyz'
you have multiple value in one column?

Yes, IinformationType can have multiple values but i am concerned about 'abc' and 'xyz' only. I have updated the question.
Please check now.

@SandeepPareek It would help if the OP [edit] the question and include the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for their sample data but it appears that they do not have multiple type columns but they do have multiple rows and the rows can contain different types.

Use conditional aggregation within an analytic function to count the number of 'abc' rows with a non-NULL datefield and then filter to only include the 'xyz' rows if there is also an 'abc' row:
SELECT informationType, dateField, valueAmount
FROM   (
  SELECT informationType, dateField, valueAmount,
         COUNT(
           CASE
           WHEN informationType = 'abc' AND dateField IS NOT NULL
           THEN 1
           END
         ) OVER () AS num_abc
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  informationType = 'abc'
  OR     (informationType = 'xyz' AND valueAmount = 0)
)
WHERE informationType = 'abc'
OR    num_abc > 0;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (informationType, dateField, valueAmount) AS
  SELECT 'abc', DATE '1970-01-01', 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', DATE '1970-01-02',   0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', DATE '1970-01-03', 200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'def', DATE '1970-01-04', 300 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



INFORMATIONTYPE
DATEFIELD
VALUEAMOUNT




abc
1970-01-01 00:00:00
100


xyz
1970-01-02 00:00:00
0



If you update the abc row to have a NULL datefield then the query outputs:



INFORMATIONTYPE
DATEFIELD
VALUEAMOUNT




abc
null
100



If you delete all the 'abc' rows then the query outputs zero rows.
fiddle

Thank you so much for your response. I have updated the question sine there are multiple columns involved and condition has been changed. Kindly refer the updated question once.

@JavaJo Updated - however your change does not fundamentally change the answer, you still use exactly the same technique with the additional filter.

@MT0 I just ran this query against the data I have but even if there was no 'abc' informationType against any row in the table, it still returns 'xyz' data row. If  'abc' informationType is not present then it should return any row. Also, 'xyz' row should only be returned with 'valueamount' field is 0.  Kindly help.

@JavaJo If you delete the abc rows then the query outputs zero rows fiddle. If you are finding something different then you need to edit your question and provide a [MRE] with the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for some sample data that replicates the problem because the query does not behave as you are suggesting.

@MT0 can you please put that additional condition for 'xyz' to be checked? 'xyz' would only be returned when 'valueAmount' = 0 for the 'xyz' information type. Currently, there is no such condition to be checked for 'xyz' informationType.

@JavaJo Have you looked at the answer? It is already there!

@MT0 I am sorry didn't realize that. You know what after that change it is working as a miracle now. You are a genious and a savior. Thank you so much mate!

I have updated the question since requirement has changed. Can you please have a look and provide your inputs.

@JavaJo Please do not bait-and-switch in your questions - if you have a follow-up then ask a new question and provide a [MRE]. In this specific case, no update is necessary - the answer already fulfils criteria 1, 2 and 3. If you want to filter for a specific informationno then add AND informationno = 123 to the WHERE clause of the inner query and if you want to return all informationno then change the count to use ... OVER (PARTITION BY informationno) but the other logic already fulfils your requirements.

I have added sample data based on the data you built the query. Can you please check it once?

I actually think you missed one condition in the where clause of the inline query.
create table test_tab
as
select 'abc'                                informationtype
     , to_date('1970-01-01','yyyy-dd-mm')   datefield
     , 100                                  amount
from dual
union all
select 'abc'
     , null    -- in the previous answer the query will also yield this row
     , 100
from dual
union all
select 'xyz'
     , to_date('1970-01-02','yyyy-dd-mm')
     , 0
from dual
union all
select 'xyz'
     , to_date('1970-01-03','yyyy-dd-mm')
     , 200
from dual
union all
select 'def'
     , to_date('1970-01-04','yyyy-dd-mm')
     , 300
from dual;
select informationtype
,      to_char(datefield,'yyyy-dd-mm')  datefield
,      amount
from   (select tab.informationtype
    ,      tab.datefield
    ,      tab.amount
    ,      count(case
                 when  tab.informationtype = 'abc'
                   and tab.datefield is not null
                 then 1
                 end) over () as num_abc
  from   test_tab                          tab
  where  ( tab.informationtype          = 'abc'
    and tab.datefield              is  not null)
  or     (  tab.informationtype         = 'xyz'
    and tab.amount                  =  0))
where informationtype = 'abc'
or    num_abc > 0;

drop table test_tab;

